# POST works in Postman, doesn't work with HTTPPOST2

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, httppost, postman

I'm trying to troubleshoot but I'm struggling. It code below works in postman, but not in the ampscript function:

```
Set @req_url = "[URL]"
Set @content_type = "application/json"

Var @body, @json, @response
    
    Set @bearerToken = Concat('Bearer ', @access_token)
    Set @body = "{"transactionId": 12345,"startingDate": "2023-09-23","numberDays": 0}"
    
set @post = HTTPPost2(@req_url,@content_type, @body, false, @json, @response,"Authorization",@bearerToken,"x-program-id","...")
```

Comment: Try changing the outer/wrapping quote marks around your entire JSON string from double to single quotes.

Comment: As @MarkG said. Its because you are using double quotes around your `@body` variable. This is breaking as its opening and closing on each double quote inside. Using Single quotes instead will resolve this.

Comment: I did change it and it still didn't work.

Comment: @en-rep is the value for `@req_url` literally `"[URL]"` right now or is that just a placeholder for this example? If `URL` is the name of the actual attribute, though, the quotes there will need to be removed.

Comment: After the HTTPPost2 function, try outputting the post, json, and response variables to see what they contain. This may give you more information about what is going wrong.

Comment: Alright so I got most of the way there. That change did reveal another error.

Now it's saying "Specified value has invalid CRLF characters. Parameter name: value" I'm guessing for my token

Turns out that when I was copying and pasting the token value for the sake of testing, line break characters were getting into the token value causing errors. Thank you all!